# Add new line to head of log file using Python

Tags: python, file-io, newline

I'm trying to add a new line in front of a date stamp in a log file. I have the following parts.

Open log file:

```
f = open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Log.file")
```

Add a new line in front of the date "25/01/2012" (uniquely identifies each log line).

```
f.write("\n" + "25/01/2012")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    f.write('\n' + "25/01/2012")
IOError: File not open for writing
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert a line in the middle of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Log.file","w");
```

by default 'r' is assumed ie reading [docs here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Note: 'w' will overwrite the existing file. Use 'a' to append

Comment: Thanks for that. You were the first to note 'w' would overwrite the entire file, which of course isn't what I wanted to do. Fortunately I made a copy and noticed your answer.

Comment: @malcmcmul Ok understood thanks :-) - I suggest you look at the answer from `Cédric Julien` as he includes some other comments regarding correct logging.

Answer (score 6):

As shown in the python documentation  for  [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), the default mode is 'r' for reading, not for 'w' for writing. Try to use :

```
f = open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Log.file", 'a')
```

to open your log file for writing (and not erasing it if it already exists)

Concerning your final goal, that is logging in files, did you have a look to the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging) which will allow you to format all your log record with date, level, PID and many usefull things ?

Answer (score 1):

```
open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Log.file", "w")
```

But please take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html for logging with Python.

**Edit:** Even better: http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need `f = open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Log.file", "w")`

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Hope this helps.